# How can i store Blob data on Redis witj .NET 4.5 async and streaming?

Tags: c#, .net, stream, redis, async-await

I need to cache blob data (images) to Redis, and get them with the new Task based API and stream the content. Ensuring that the web server does NOT hold the whole image in memory (as a byte[]).

Any way to get both async and to stream the data back, not getting all data as a byte[]?

Comment: Does the API let you use `Stream`?

Comment: Actually I need to find an API that allows this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ReadAsync/WriteAsync to asynchronously read and write the data in chunks.  The byte[] that you will write will not be the whole image but just a buffer to contain the chunks.

Check out http://redis.io/clients for a list of available redis clients.  https://github.com/ctstone/csredis looks promising as it already uses Tasks in it's Async interface.

Comment: What Client API allowes this? Do you have an example?

Comment: You're looking for a redis specific API?